# How to fix bug found by findbugs "Method accesses list or array with constant index"

Tags: java, spring, findbugs

java code:

```
p.setCode((String) fileds[1]);
p.setTitle((String) fileds[2]);
p.setLogo((String) fileds[3]);
p.setMaxBorrowAmt((Integer) fileds[4]);
p.setMinBorrowAmt((Integer) fileds[5]);
```

fileds[] is Object array,it's created by Spring-Data-JPA to select something from 3 different tables;

```
@Query(
   value="select a.id,a.code,b.title,b.logo,c.max from tableA a left join TableB b left join TableC c where ... ",
   nativeQuery = true
)
List<Object[]> findSomething();
```

findbugs warning:

Method accesses list or array with constant index

This method accesses an array or list using a constant integer index. Often, this is a typo where a loop variable is intended to be used. If however, specific list indices mean different specific things, then perhaps replacing the list with a first-class object with meaningful accessors would make the code less brittle.

how should I fix this bug?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `fileds` is probably a typo and should be `fields`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a final Integer Constant instead

```
public static final Integer CODE_POSITION = 0;

//other code

p.setCode((String) fileds[CODE_POSITION]);

//rest of the code...
```

Answer (score -2):

Create Custom Class

```
public class CustomClass{
private String code;
private String title;
// rest goes here 
//all setter getter 
}
```

and then replace method signature `List<Object[]> findSomething();` with `List<CustomClass> findSomething();`

And Access the listItem using below code snap.

```
p.setCode(listItem.getCode());
p.setTitle(listItem.getTitle());
```